# SSRS DateTime Parameter Force Time

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report that lets the user pass a start time and end time into a query.

The start time works perfectly as it automatically selects 00:00:00 for the time.

However the end time also selects the same time and I would like it to auto select 11:59:59.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want it to select 11:59:59 because you are using something like `WHERE DateField BETWEEN @StartTime AND @EndTime`? Could you not change it to `WHERE DateField >= @StartTime AND DateField < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndTime)`, then it wouldn't matter that @EndTime had a time of 00:00.

Comment: You might have hit the nail on the head! Thanks

Comment: @GarethD, you should post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should very rarely be a need for setting a date parameter with a time of `23:59:59`, usually when this is the case it is because you are using something like:

```
WHERE DateTimeField BETWEEN @DateTime1 AND @DateTime2;
```

Which is best avoided, [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) has gone into far more detail than I could in an answer here in his article [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), but the long and the short of it is that when working with DATETIME it is almost always preferential to use something like

```
WHERE DateField >= @DateTime1
AND DateField < @DateTime2;
```

Although this can cause some confusion to users who are expecting that if they choose and end date parameter of 15th August 2013, it will include data from that date, so you may need to use:

```
WHERE DateField >= @DateTime1
AND DateField < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTime2);
```

Comment: Another thing to consider is that if you do use DateTimeField BETWEEN @DateTime1 AND @DateTime2; then any DateTimeField value between 2311:59:59 and 00:00:00 of the next day will be left out (eg., 23:59:59.123)